# Largest sentient biped in EU/Legends?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In *The Force Awakens*, at first appearance of Leader Snoke it looked like he was a giant, which made me sad because AFAIK there are no giant humanoids/bipeds in Star Wars.

Chewie is tall but not outside the range of human height. Hutts are big but not outlandishly so (in the range of everyday animals humans see on earth, like a cow), and are not humanoid.

There's a pretty big alien in Maz's castle in *TFA*, but not near the same scale as Snoke appeared, and only a bit larger than the largest super obese humans I'd say from my memory. The Rancor is bipedal but not sentient. Anyway, a giant humanoid seemed really outside the band of Star Wars style that I know of.  So I was relieved to realize Snoke was shown only in giant hologram form, so he is (hopefully) not actually a giant.

But I only know the movies.

**Are there giant sentient bipeds in the extended universe?**  By giant lets define that as being significantly (2x or more) larger than the largest known humans in real life. By bipeds I mean humanoid body styles, two legs and two arms. And by sentient I mean intelligent.

Comment: One wookiee sitting on another wookiee's shoulders.  Or seven ewoks standing on each other's shoulders.

Comment: @zipquincy - as you say, we only see Snoke in hologram form. Likely similar to the enormous appearance of the Emperor's hologram in Empire Strikes Back, the video feed may not always correlate to actual size. By all accounts, if Snoke turns out to be who theories speculate he is, he will likely only be around 7ft tall

Comment: Actually Rancors are semisentient, IIRC from my EU canon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I haven't found a full canon confirmation, but [Frost Giants](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Frost_Giant) on Endor probably were humanoid; and were large enough that Ewok fit into their palm:

  [image]

  Source: EU/Legends, Marvel Ewoks Annual, "The Ice Pricess".
- [Gorax](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gorax/Legends) were semi-sentient, humanoid and 6 ft tall.

  They are actually [Disney canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gorax)
- [Mandallian giants](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandallian_Giant)

  No exact height but seem far bigger than 2x of a human based on Wookieepedia picture.
- [Phlogs](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Phlog)

  20 meters high. They were found everywhere but on Endor as well. I'm sensing a theme here.
- [Gargantelles of Boz Pity](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gargantelle)

  20 meters tall, extinct, and humanoid but with 6 arms.
- [Esoomians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Esoomian)

  3 meters tall

Comment: Wow, the forest moon is crawling with sentient species!

Comment: Where were the Frost Giants and Phlogs when a C-3PO led teddy bear army was throwing sticks at AT-ATs? I would've much preferred that version...